# Electron builder Application name in programs list without version on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, nsis, electron-builder

Im using electron builder and have set `name` and `productName` in `package.json` of my electron app, but when I make the installer using `nsis` and install the application on windows, In the applications list or programs list in windows settings it shows version in the name of the application which I dont want, so is there `configuration` of `electron-builder` or `nsis` that I can use to make that work ? [You can see the issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4P52.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis) you can use the `uninstallDisplayName` option to define a different name for the uninstall menu:

```
"build": {
  "productName": "MyApp",
  "nsis": {
    "artifactName": "MyApp.setup.${version}.${ext}",
    "uninstallDisplayName": "MyApp"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: I found a wat to exlude the version in your installer name: "artifactName": "App Name.${ext}"

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put your version in `package.json`
For example:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "build": {
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah I have that and everything else is fine, but on windows when I go to application list in windows settings page after installing the application, it shows the application name and version appended together which I dont want.